# Cannot print array slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm playing around with Go language, using its online playground.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    primes := [6]int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}

    var s []int = primes[1:6]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

This code prints nothing. Changing slice range to something else, for instance to `[2:6]` works as expected. I have tried it only using Go playground. [Check it here.](https://play.golang.org/p/wdLUlXigcv)

Why it doesn't print anything? Probably it can be a Go compiler or Go playground bug, however I don't know the language so I'm not sure.

Comment: It just looks like a bad result was cached somehow. Changing the source slightly to get a new run shows output: https://play.golang.org/p/9JCVkOwWD8

Comment: If you add a dummy `fmt.Println("")`, you see that your expected result appears. It seems that the program exits before the buffer is flushed. Also, it works as expected when I execute locally.

Answer (score 0):

A few month later (June 2017), even the [original example](https://play.golang.org/p/wdLUlXigcv) does work with the current iteration of the [`golang/playground`](https://github.com/golang/playground).

That means the flushing issue after a `fmt.Println` as a last instruction of main() has been fixed.